# Qt Folder organization

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qt6

I am learning Qt6 in Qt Creator 8.0.2 (Community) with C++ on Windows. I have a project( Qt Widgets Application) with Qmake as the build system. When I open the project in Creator it is well organized, that is, the headers(.h files) are in a header folder, sources(.cpp files) are in sources folder, etc. Like so:

```
LearningQt
-LearningQt.pro
-Headers\
    -mainwindow.h
-Sources\
    -main.cpp
    -mainwindow.cpp
-Forms\
    -mainwindow.ui
```

But when I open the project in File explorer all the files are in the root directory. Like so:

```
LearningQt
-LearningQt.pro
-LearningQt.pro.user
-mainwindow.h
-main.cpp
-mainwindow.cpp
-mainwindow.ui
```

My question is that is it possible to organize the project files in folders in File explorer?

Comment: Ask one question at time. Also these are confusingly basic questions. Do you have idea how to make directories for example named "include" and "src"? Do you have idea how to put files into those directories? What are you missing?

Comment: Sorry for that I could not understand the answers in the other posts regarding this so I thought I could ask them all at once Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can reorganise file locations. It is still unclear from your question what problems you have with it.

You just have to mimic whatever the changes you made on your storage directories in your *.pro file as well. QtCreator will usually understand what you did on the fly. If it does not then you erase or empty its temporary files in build directories. Here for example how to do it when you want absolute paths. The variable `$$PWD` is location of the .pro file itself:

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
    $$PWD/Headers

HEADERS += \
    $$PWD/Headers/mainwindow.h

SOURCES += \
    $$PWD/Sources/main.cpp \
    $$PWD/Sources/mainwindow.cpp
```

Or other such changes. The *.pro is relatively simple and intuitive project file compared to other build systems like CMake, makefiles, XCode or Visual Studio project files. Also it is quite [well documented](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-advanced-usage.html). If you have concrete questions about particular feature of it then ask it in some other question.

Comment: So it means that have to manually create the folders and update the paths for each file right?

Comment: You can of course remove, rename and add the files in QtCreator IDE itself to project. In simpler project it is usually OK, but in more complex projects consisting of subprojects (for libraries/modules) it can be is confused. So I myself edit those files manually.

Comment: Example reason why I like full paths is that sometimes it has happened that multiple subprojects had file with same name and qmake was confused with it.